# What can cause performance degradation when users upload to MOSS?

Tags: 2007, anti-virus

My client has a farm with MOSS 2007. Recently they upgraded to SharePoint Service Pack 2. Since the patch we have noticed that the CPU's on the server spike when users upload files. We are not sure whether the cause is the service pack, the fact that we are using Trend Micro OfficeScan Client 8.0 (not designed for SharePoint), or some other factor. Are there know issues with Service Pack 2 or OfficeScan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case,  it was a contractors EventReceiver used on every site that kicked off a reindex when a user did a multiple file upload. So a user would upload multiple files, and every site would then start the reindex. I'm getting this information second hand. I'll add details as I learn them.

Answer (score 2):

To test if the virus scanner is causing the problem, you could also disable the virus scanner and reproduce the CPU spike behaviour to see if the problem dissapear. If it doesnt, try and use products like Process Explorer from [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com) (part of Microsoft now) to see what process is responsible for the CPU spike.

If this really is an anti virus case, you should make sure you set up file exclusion to avoid the virus scanner bogging down performance.

Files like log files and templates etc in the SharePoint root (12 hive) should be excluded from scanning or performance may suffer

I read that especially WSS_adminservice.log can cause CPU spikes.

C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Local Settings\Temp\WSS_AdminService.log

Answer (score 0):

Is the farm set to run a virus-scan after a file is uploaded?  I don't have a 2007 sharepoint install handy, but you can look in central admin for the setting.

Comment: Trend Micro does real-time scanning throughout the day and a full scan at the end of the day.